# Filtering video embed text out of search result text while using Search API

Tags: views, search

I'm using the Search API module to improve my Drupal 8 site's search functionality, and I'm using the Video Embed Media module for the purposes of embedding YouTube and Vimeo content. I have created a view that renders my search results, but I'm running in to a problem with the raw video embed text appearing in the results. I can eliminate this problem if I use entity field rendering in the view settings for the body field, but if I do that I give up the ability to highlight the original search term(s) in the results. This looks like an either/or situation. I want both! Anyone have a solution to this problem?